# Git - export archive with commit history

Tags: git, github

How do I archive export a git repository at a specified commit **with commit history**?

Using `git archive --output=test.zip 898a4ca` exports the files but there is no .git, and hence no commit history or branches.

Basically I want to be able to export a git repo at a certain point in time - including the commit history and branches to that point.

This is useful for giving clients a copy of the repo up until the milestones they have paid for.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git bundle` to do that:

```
git bundle create <filename> <commit you want>
```

See the documentation for more details: http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle